# using vagrant, php ftp functions and curl ftp not working, but node with promise-ftp work, why?

Tags: php, node.js, curl, ftp, vagrant

I'm using a vagrant box and i'm trying to connect to an ftp with php native ftp functions. But, even if i can login to the ftp without an issue, i can't do an ftp_nlist, even if i do a ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) after the login.

i tried to connect with curl but i got this :

```
* Rebuilt URL to: ftp://ftp.cluster017.ovh.net/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 213.186.33.215...
* Connected to ftp.cluster017.ovh.net (213.186.33.215) port 21 (#0)
< 220-  ~~~ Welcome to OVH ~~~
< 220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
> USER blablaOne
< 331 User blablaOne OK. Password required
> PASS 123456789
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||30866|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 213.186.33.215...
* Connecting to 213.186.33.215 (213.186.33.215) port 30866
* Connected to ftp.cluster017.ovh.net (213.186.33.215) port 21 (#0)
> TYPE A
```

it hang after TYPE A.

i found out that there is a problem with the Vagrant NAT but i tried to do the connection in JS with nodeJS and ... it worked ! i can connect and list my files and folders.

i did some tcp dump for nodeJS :

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:13:10.150087 IP 10.0.2.15.34220 > 10.0.2.3.domain: 7535+ A? ftp.cluster017.ovh.net. (40)
11:13:10.150168 IP 10.0.2.15.34220 > 10.0.2.3.domain: 52103+ AAAA? ftp.cluster017.ovh.net. (40)
11:13:10.159348 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [S], seq 2771820375, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 27617755 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:13:10.169226 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [S.], seq 1427810817, ack 2771820376, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
11:13:10.169328 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [.], ack 1, win 29200, length 0
11:13:10.177066 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 1:82, ack 1, win 65535, length 81
11:13:10.177162 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [.], ack 82, win 29200, length 0
11:13:10.182122 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 82, win 29200, length 17
11:13:10.182466 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [.], ack 18, win 65535, length 0
11:13:10.192028 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 82:125, ack 18, win 65535, length 43
11:13:10.194317 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 18:37, ack 125, win 29200, length 19
11:13:10.194608 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [.], ack 37, win 65535, length 0
11:13:10.213106 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 125:168, ack 37, win 65535, length 43
11:13:10.213666 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 37:43, ack 168, win 29200, length 6
11:13:10.213954 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [.], ack 43, win 65535, length 0
11:13:10.227436 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 168:408, ack 43, win 65535, length 240
11:13:10.229282 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 43:51, ack 408, win 30016, length 8
11:13:10.229609 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [.], ack 51, win 65535, length 0
11:13:10.242499 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 408:438, ack 51, win 65535, length 30
11:13:10.253906 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 51:57, ack 438, win 30016, length 6
11:13:10.254568 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [.], ack 57, win 65535, length 0
11:13:10.262489 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 438:490, ack 57, win 65535, length 52
11:13:10.265273 IP 10.0.2.15.40551 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.51418: Flags [S], seq 1804817367, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 27617782 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:13:10.275803 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.51418 > 10.0.2.15.40551: Flags [S.], seq 1427874817, ack 1804817368, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
11:13:10.275896 IP 10.0.2.15.40551 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.51418: Flags [.], ack 1, win 29200, length 0
11:13:10.277375 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 57:74, ack 490, win 30016, length 17
11:13:10.277691 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [.], ack 74, win 65535, length 0
11:13:10.286910 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.51418 > 10.0.2.15.40551: Flags [P.], seq 1:349, ack 1, win 65535, length 348
11:13:10.287001 IP 10.0.2.15.40551 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.51418: Flags [.], ack 349, win 30016, length 0
11:13:10.287058 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.51418 > 10.0.2.15.40551: Flags [R.], seq 349, ack 1, win 65535, length 0
11:13:10.287079 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 490:520, ack 74, win 65535, length 30
11:13:10.287498 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.51418 > 10.0.2.15.40551: Flags [R], seq 1427875166, win 0, length 0
11:13:10.296830 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 520:562, ack 74, win 65535, length 42
11:13:10.297048 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [.], ack 562, win 30016, length 0
11:13:10.321630 IP 10.0.2.15.39034 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [F.], seq 74, ack 562, win 30016, length 0
11:13:10.322072 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [.], ack 75, win 65535, length 0
11:13:10.334163 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [P.], seq 562:575, ack 75, win 65535, length 13
11:13:10.334239 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39034: Flags [F.], seq 575, ack 75, win 65535, length 0
^C88 packets captured
91 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

and for curl:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:13:35.219787 IP 10.0.2.15.35547 > 10.0.2.3.domain: 48380+ A? ftp.cluster017.ovh.net. (40)
11:13:35.219853 IP 10.0.2.15.35547 > 10.0.2.3.domain: 28845+ AAAA? ftp.cluster017.ovh.net. (40)
11:13:35.248939 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [S], seq 2365319719, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 27624028 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:13:35.260525 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [S.], seq 1430882817, ack 2365319720, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
11:13:35.260618 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [.], ack 1, win 29200, length 0
11:13:35.268533 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 1:82, ack 1, win 65535, length 81
11:13:35.268650 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [.], ack 82, win 29200, length 0
11:13:35.269153 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 82, win 29200, length 17
11:13:35.269402 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [.], ack 18, win 65535, length 0
11:13:35.285199 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 82:125, ack 18, win 65535, length 43
11:13:35.285457 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 18:37, ack 125, win 29200, length 19
11:13:35.285722 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [.], ack 37, win 65535, length 0
11:13:35.313794 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 125:168, ack 37, win 65535, length 43
11:13:35.314136 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 37:42, ack 168, win 29200, length 5
11:13:35.315605 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [.], ack 42, win 65535, length 0
11:13:35.324667 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 168:202, ack 42, win 65535, length 34
11:13:35.324953 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 42:48, ack 202, win 29200, length 6
11:13:35.325462 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [.], ack 48, win 65535, length 0
11:13:35.334062 IP truncated-ip - 6 bytes missing! ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 202:250, ack 48, win 65535, length 48
11:13:36.254880 IP 10.0.2.3.domain > 10.0.2.15.35650: 32363 1/0/0 PTR ftp.cluster017.ovh.net. (81)
11:13:37.256837 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 202:244, ack 48, win 65535, length 42
11:13:37.257175 IP 10.0.2.15.53303 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.30866: Flags [S], seq 2908556650, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 27624530 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:13:37.272756 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.30866 > 10.0.2.15.53303: Flags [S.], seq 1431202817, ack 2908556651, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
11:13:37.272828 IP 10.0.2.15.53303 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.30866: Flags [.], ack 1, win 29200, length 0
11:13:37.273048 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 48:56, ack 244, win 29200, length 8
11:13:37.273293 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [.], ack 56, win 65535, length 0
11:13:37.282702 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 250:273, ack 56, win 65535, length 23
11:13:37.282756 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [.], ack 244, win 30016, length 0
11:13:40.288808 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 250:273, ack 56, win 65535, length 23
11:13:40.288863 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [.], ack 244, win 30016, length 0
11:13:46.297849 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 250:273, ack 56, win 65535, length 23
11:13:46.297905 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [.], ack 244, win 30016, length 0
11:13:52.772195 IP 10.0.2.15.53303 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.30866: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 29200, length 0
11:13:52.772313 IP 10.0.2.15.39036 > ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp: Flags [F.], seq 56, ack 244, win 30016, length 0
11:13:52.772606 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.30866 > 10.0.2.15.53303: Flags [.], ack 2, win 65535, length 0
11:13:52.772638 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [.], ack 57, win 65535, length 0
11:13:52.787103 IP ftp.cluster017.ovh.net.ftp > 10.0.2.15.39036: Flags [P.], seq 273:286, ack 57, win 65535, length 13
```

We can see that it hang but i dont understand why ?! So why does it work with node and not with php and curl ?